# My Android email code broken after version updates

Tags: android, email

I have an app that I recently brought up to the latest version of Android along with Android Studio. The app has the ability to email an attached file to an email recipient. It used to work. However, it no longer attaches designated zip file, doesn't load the email recipient address into the email, and when the result (it calls startActivityForResult) comes back, the result code is 0 which is not RESULT_OK. So the email is never delivered.

```
            ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<>();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "Emailing Survey",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("application/zip");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, Settings.emailRecipient);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Survey Attached");
            File zipFile = new File(zipFileName);
            zipFile.setReadable(true, false);
            Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
            final Uri u = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, "com.example.kustomsignalsinc.traffictrakv1.provider", zipFile);
            mContext.grantUriPermission(mContext.getPackageName(), u, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            String authority = u.getAuthority();
            uris.add(u);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, u);
            if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {

                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
                startActivityForResult(intent,2);

            }
        }
    }
```

The email app comes up but the (intent putExtra EXTRA_EMAIL) fails as does the (intent putExtra EXTRA_STEAM). IOW, no address, no attachment. But the email subject was added.
The debug console shows this error:

````
W/Bundle: Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable
        at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:945)
        at android.content.Intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.java:7167)
        at android.content.Intent.migrateExtraStreamToClipData(Intent.java:10003)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1611)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4501)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:676)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4459)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:663)
        at com.example.kustomsignalsinc.traffictrakv1.SurveyActivity.saveSurveyFiles(SurveyActivity.java:795)
        at com.example.kustomsignalsinc.traffictrakv1.SurveyActivity.handlePL4Response(SurveyActivity.java:864)
        at com.example.kustomsignalsinc.traffictrakv1.SurveyActivity$1.handleMessage(SurveyActivity.java:142)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6526)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)```

Line 795 is the (intent.putParceableArrayListExtra) function call.
````

Comment: "when the result (it calls startActivityForResult) comes back, the result code is 0 which is not RESULT_OK" -- [`ACTION_SEND` does not return a result](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/Intent#action_send). So, I recommend switching to `startActivity()`. Also, [`EXTRA_STREAM` takes a single `Uri`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/Intent#EXTRA_STREAM:kotlin.String), not an `ArrayList<Uri>`. Also, your `grantUriPermission()` call and your `setResult()` calls are pointless and can be removed.

Comment: That fixed some of the issues. However, it is still not adding the recipient address to the email. I have to add it manually. When I run the debugger and hover over the recipient string, it shows the correct address.

Comment: "However, it is still not adding the recipient address to the email" -- there is no requirement for any app to honor every extra. Plus, [`EXTRA_EMAIL` is documented to take a string array, not a string](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/Intent#extra_email).

Comment: Okay. BTW, thank you for the assistance.